# I am trying to add packages to my .net 5 project but i get these errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
-error: NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.2 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
error: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\Dimitrije\Desktop\webAPI\Proba\Proba.csproj'.

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
-error: NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.2 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
error: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\Dimitrije\Desktop\webAPI\Proba\Proba.csproj'.
```

Comment: You should try version 5.0.17 when using .net5 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/5.0.17

Comment: so i should type dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -v 5.0.17 ?

Comment: @РакићевићДимитрије or consider updating to dotnet 7 - this is usually pretty painless (although do check the release notes, as always any changes could potentially impact you)

Comment: use the nuget GUI to downgrade the version of the package, its much easier. (you can find it in tools)

Comment: .Net Core 5 is out of official support, you should be updating your code base to .Net Core 6 or 7. Odd number .Net Core versions are supported for 18 months, Even number versions are supported for 36 months. (3 years) This is considerably different to .Net Framework development where Framework version support was linked to Operating System support commitments. .Net Core development requires projects to upgrade on an ongoing basis.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlserver version >= 6.x.x requires .net6, use sqlserver with version 5.x.x with .net5